# Abstract class constructor and derived classes

Tags: c#

```
abstract class Shape
{
    public Shape(string name = "NoName") { PetName = name; }
    public string PetName { get; set; }
    public abstract void Draw();
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle() { }
    public Circle(string name) : base(name) { }
    public override void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing {0} the Circle", PetName);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.Draw();
    }
}
```

I'm interested in the line **public Circle() { }**.
If this constructor is, the console will display the message *"Drawing NoName the Circle"*

Why so? Does it inherit the constructor of the base class **Shape**? Then why do we need to define an empty constructor in a derived class **Circle**?

Comment: No, constructors are never inherited in C#. (Not enough time to write a fuller answer right now, but that's basically it. There may well be a duplicate somewhere.)

Comment: If not specified the default constructor will be called on the base class and apparently a constructor with all default parameters is good enough to be a default constructor.  So `public Circle() {}` is basically the same as `public Circle() : base() {}`

Comment: @juharr Then why does the PetName property have the value NoName?

Comment: Because that's the default value you set for it in `public Shape(string name = "NoName")`

Comment: @juharr and to add to your comment... OP, you didn't specify a name when calling `new Circle();` in the `Program` class so it used the default constructor. Calling `new Circle("NewName"); would override the name in the base class with "NewName".

Comment: A constructor in each type of the inheritance chain _must_ be called when the object is instantiated. A parameterless constructor or a parameterized constructor where all parameters have default values will be called implicitly if you do not explicitly specify the base constructor to call. So that's what happened here. See duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it inherit the constructor of the base class Shape?

From C# [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#instance-constructors):

> Instance constructors are not inherited. Thus, a class has no instance constructors other than those actually declared in the class. If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided

So `Circle` does not inherit any constructor from `Shape`, it calls it. The [next specification section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#constructor-initializers) can shed some light:

> All instance constructors (except those for class `object`) implicitly include an invocation of another instance constructor immediately before the constructor_body. The constructor to implicitly invoke is determined by the constructor_initializer:
>
> - An instance constructor initializer of the form base(argument_list) or base() causes an instance constructor from the direct base class to be invoked. That constructor is selected using argument_list if present and the overload resolution rules of [Overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#overload-resolution).

So compiler uses the existing `Shape` constructor with default value for `name` i.e.

```
public Circle() { }
```

Transforms [into](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACgA7AQwFsYBnAB2rBgAIBhdgbwuuAMALlFZD2RdgGUAFtSYwKfcu1USAzNLkKAFPmIAGdjXrsAvOwBEAOQjW6MSwEpe7AAowh90xZMwA3OwAvhRqGhKG7p7eHDzsAOaegQxJwaFq+JoCwqJg4vgo7AAiogDuOk7+FCHkFJKcAJZQYAA2HCBa8orkymGZXE2tMBWuNX2aEABuMFBQDRgcBcVlFemqvWEZxACcOpYl1KUNlPG8BkHsQjIcjc1tlmhRXg6Va2nkNUFAA):

```
public Circle() : base("NoName")
{
}
```

If you will delete the default value for `name` in `Shape` constructor then you will see compilation error marking that compiler can't find suitable constructor overload for the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are never inherited. Rather, each class needs its own constructor. That means that you call one constructor for each level of inheritance.

**Then why do we need to define an empty constructor in a derived class Circle?**
Generally, you don't need to do that. When there is no constructor given, the default empty constructor is automatically added. However, in this case you do need the empty constructor because you call `Circle c = new Circle();` and the default empty constructor isn't created because `public Circle(string name)` is defined.

In short: You only ever need to define the empty constructor when your code uses it and there is a non-empty constructor defined.